# Persist file redirection between exec calls

Tags: bash, stdout, exec

Is there a way to persist file redirection commands between exec calls?

For example, there are two bash scripts. In script 1, I am setting up redirection of stdout and stderr to file. Then exec-ing script2.

script1

```
exec &> >(tee "$logs_file")
echo "something"
exec "./script2.sh"
```

script2

```
echo "something else
```

Inside log file only the echo commands from script 1 appear but not script 2.

```
something
```

Is there a way to persist file redirection commands between exec calls?

Comment: You've accepted my answer (thank you). Have you worked out why it wasn't working for you originally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing a couple of minor errors in your example, I don't see the problem you describe

```
# Set up the scenario
mkdir /tmp/555270
cd /tmp/555270

cat <<'EOF' >script1
#!/bin/bash
logs_file=logs_file
exec &> >(tee "$logs_file")
echo "something"
exec "./script2"
EOF

cat <<'EOF' >script2
#!/bin/bash
echo "something else"
EOF

chmod a+x script?
rm -f logs_file

# Run the script
./script1
something
something else

# Examine the log file
cat logs_file
something
something else
```